# MS Reporting Services - run subreports multiple times within 1 report output

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have 2 reports, first one is an Authorization Form and the second one prints RMA Tags, all that is needed to run these reports is an RMA #

A third report is used so that I can have 2 sub reports (one for the Auth Form and one for the Tags) on it so that they can run 1 report and get all of the data that they need in 1 spot. This report has an RMA # as a parameter and passes this to the 2 subreports.

Everything works just fine but I want to provide the capability to accept a comma delimited value of RMA #'s and then run the Auth Form/RMA Tag subreport combination for each RMA # and I am unsure on how to set up my parameters for the main report and how to call the subreports multiple times from the main report.

I hope I have explained this well enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend trying to place the sub reports within a group by table for the value that would distinguish a new sub report...